# Display Cart in .NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, shopping-cart

Currently, I am saving Cart in Database and I will display it in `_Layout`.

I can't use `@model` to display the products or quantity in the Cart because it will conflict with other `Views`. If I use `ViewBag` then I will need to call it out in different `Controllers`.

So is there any other solution here where I can display the quantity in the cart and display the products out?

Comment: Define a request-scoped DI service that you inject into your Layout view that acts as a data-source for cart data. Request-scoped services have access to `HttpContext` (e.g. for cookies and session state).

Comment: If you are displaying it in your layout root, that implies it will be part of every view model. What's the issue?

Answer (score -1):

You can try using localStorage of browser. pushed your quantity or product object to local storage i.e
localStorage.setItem("quantity ", quantity); fetch it when you need to display.

Comment: That doesn't help because they still need to get the cart's contents in the first place, not to mention this won't work at all for someone with JavaScript disabled. Also, you're limited to the amount and type of information you can store in `localStorage` - and then consider if the user wants to use their cart between different devices (e.g. their phone, tablet, and desktop) or saving their cart for later, etc.